# mozjpeg on server with jpegtran with same result like in Squoosh

Tags: jpegtran, mozjpeg

I installed mozjpeg on my server and tried to get the same compress result like in Squoosh Webinterface with mozjpeg

1. I compressed an image in Squoosh Webinterface. 
   Original image:  testimage_original.jpg (324kb) 
   compressed image: testimage_squoosh_75.jpg(51kb) (75% and compress with mozjpeg)
2. Test on server:
   /opt/mozjpeg/bin/jpegtran -copy none -progressive -optimize /var/www/vhosts/testpage.de/httpdocs/test-local/testimage.jpg > /var/www/vhosts/testpage.de/httpdocs/test-local/compressed.jpg

   result is only a to 267kb compressed file.

how can i reach a nearly the same compression on my server?

Answer (score -1):

```
/opt/mozjpeg/bin/cjpeg -q 75 xxx.jpg > xxx1.jpg
```

Comment: You should include a brief description explaining what this snippet does.